# Not starting background service using android WorkManager

Tags: android, android-workmanager, background-service

Actually I want to record voice call from background (forground) in android Oreo and later. But i am not able to find where the problems. If I use the same code using JobSchedular/Service with startFroground(id,notification) then it is fine but if I use WorkManager then is not showing any forground notification and not recording audio. please see my code and explain me.

```
    public class MyWorkManager extends Worker {

    private MediaRecorder recorder;
    private boolean recordStarted = false;
    private boolean serviceStarted = false;
    private boolean recordStart;
    private boolean serviceStart;
    private boolean hasException = false;
    private File file;
    private Database database;
    private String filePath;
    private String callIndicator;
    CharSequence userDate;
    CharSequence userMonth;
    CharSequence userYear;
    CharSequence userTime;
    CharSequence fileTime;
    private MediaMetadataRetriever mmr;
    private Uri uri;
    private String duration;
    private String contactName = null;


    public MyWorkManager(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull WorkerParameters workerParams) {
        super(context, workerParams);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Result doWork() {
        Data data=getInputData();
        recordStart = data.getBoolean("RecordStart", false);
        serviceStart = data.getBoolean("ServiceStart", false);
        if (serviceStart) {
            callIndicator = data.getString("CallIndicator");
        }

        if (serviceStart && Constants.phoneNumber != null && !serviceStarted) {
            startService();
        } else if (!serviceStart && serviceStarted) {
            stopService();
        }
        return Result.success();
    }



    public void startService() {
        if (serviceStart && !serviceStarted && callIndicator != null && Constants.phoneNumber != null) {
            if (!Constants.onForground) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), HomeActivity.class);
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
                PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                        getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, 0);
                Notification notification;
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 26) {
                    notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                            getApplicationContext(), MY_NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID)
                            .setContentTitle("Call Recorder Easy & Simple")
                            .setTicker("hi")
                            .setContentText("Click to see about new recorded file")
                            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent).setOngoing(true)
                            .build();
                } else {
                    notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                            getApplicationContext())
                            .setContentTitle("Call Recorder Easy & Simple")
                            .setTicker("hi")
                            .setContentText("Click to see about new recorded file")
                            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent).setOngoing(true)
                            .build();
                }

                notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR;
                ForegroundInfo foregroundInfo=new ForegroundInfo(1336,notification);
                setForegroundAsync(foregroundInfo);
            }
            startRecording();
            Constants.onForground = true;
            serviceStarted = true;
            recordStarted = true;
        }
    }

    public void stopService() {
        if (!serviceStart && serviceStarted) {
            if (recordStarted) {
                stopRecording(Constants.phoneNumber);
                serviceStarted = false;
                recordStarted = false;
                callIndicator = null;
            }
            showNotification();
            Constants.onForground = false;
            Constants.workManager.cancelAllWork();
        }
    }

    public Database getDatabaseInstance() {
        if (database == null) {
            database = new Database(getApplicationContext());
        }
        return database;
    }

    public MediaMetadataRetriever getMmrInstance() {
        if (mmr == null) {
            mmr = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
        }
        return mmr;
    }

    public String getContactName(final String phoneNumber, Context context) {
        Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(phoneNumber));

        String[] projection = new String[]{ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME};

        Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, null);

        if (cursor != null) {
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                contactName = cursor.getString(0);
            }
            cursor.close();
        }
        if (contactName == null) {
            contactName = phoneNumber;
        }
        return contactName;
    }

    public void startRecording() {
        if (recordStart && !recordStarted) {
            Log.d("Abdullah","record starting");
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Record Starting", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), ".EasyAndSimple");
            final Date date = new Date();
            userDate = DateFormat.format("dd", date.getTime());
            userMonth = DateFormat.format("MM", date.getTime());
            userYear = DateFormat.format("yyyy", date.getTime());
            userTime = DateFormat.format("hh.mm", date.getTime());
            fileTime = DateFormat.format("hh.mm.ss", date.getTime());


            try {
                recorder = new MediaRecorder();
                recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.DEFAULT);
                recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
                recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
                if (!file.exists()) {
                    file.mkdirs();
                }
                filePath = file.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + userDate + "-" + userMonth + "-" + userYear + "-" + fileTime + "rec.3gp";
                recorder.setOutputFile(filePath);
                recorder.prepare();
                Thread.sleep(2000);
                recorder.start();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                hasException = true;
            }
            recordStarted = true;
        }
    }

    public void stopRecording(String phoneNumber) {
        if (recorder != null && recordStarted) {
            Log.d("Abdullah","stopping recording");
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Record Stopping", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            try {
                recorder.stop();
                recorder.reset();
                recorder.release();
                recordStarted = false;
                getDatabaseInstance();
                getMmrInstance();
                uri = Uri.parse(filePath);
                mmr.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(), uri);
                duration = mmr.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_DURATION);
                contactName = getContactName(phoneNumber, getApplicationContext());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                hasException = true;
            }
            if (database != null && !hasException) {
                database.initializedDatabase();
                database.insertData(String.valueOf(userDate), String.valueOf(userMonth), String.valueOf(userYear), new CallListModelClass(callIndicator, duration, contactName, String.valueOf(userTime), filePath));
                database.closeDatabase();
            }
            database = null;
            mmr = null;
            recorder = null;
        }
    }

    public void showNotification() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 26) {
            NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                    new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext(), MY_NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID)
                            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                            .setContentTitle("New Recording")
                            .setContentText("A phone Call has been Recorded");
            Intent resultIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), HomeActivity.class);
            PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, resultIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
            NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
                    (NotificationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            mNotificationManager.notify(1, mBuilder.build());
        } else {
            NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                    new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                            .setContentTitle("New Recording")
                            .setContentText("A phone Call has been Recorded");
            Intent resultIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), HomeActivity.class);
            PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, resultIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
            NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
                    (NotificationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            mNotificationManager.notify(1, mBuilder.build());
        }

    }

}
```

// This is my two methods that is use to start and stop or schedule workmanager

```
private void startWorkManager(Context context){
    if (!Constants.isRecordStarted && Constants.callIndicator != null && Constants.phoneNumber != null) {
        Data data=new Data.Builder()
                .putBoolean("RecordStart",true)
                .putBoolean("ServiceStart",true)
                .putString("PhoneNumber",Constants.phoneNumber)
                .putString("CallIndicator",Constants.callIndicator)
                .build();
        OneTimeWorkRequest workRequest=new OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(MyWorkManager.class)
                .setInputData(data)
                .addTag("MyTag")
                .build();
        Constants.workManager.enqueue(workRequest);
        Constants.isRecordStarted = true;
    }
}

private void stopWorkManager(Context context){
    if (Constants.isRecordStarted) {
        Data data=new Data.Builder()
                .putBoolean("ServiceStart",false)
                .build();
        OneTimeWorkRequest workRequest=new OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(MyWorkManager.class)
                .setInputData(data)
                .addTag("MyTag")
                .build();
        Constants.workManager.enqueue(workRequest);
        Constants.isRecordStarted = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: show the code where you schedule your work.